# Swift: IBAction to put image in UIImageView after a button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, ibaction

I'm working in Swift and I'm trying to create a simple IBAction that puts an image (that I've already loaded in my assets) into a UIImageView once a button is clicked.

I've control-dragged and hooked everything up and yet I'm getting this error: 
"cannot convert expressions type '()' to type 'UIImage!'"
I'm a beginner so please explain all answers thoroughly. 
My code:

```
@IBAction func colorBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        colorsPanel.image = "Red_colors_panel"

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the solution? Does it solves the problem?

Comment: Yes thank you that ended up working

Comment: If answer solved you problem, mark it as accepted. If it does not then please leave a comment what does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to pass an `UIImage` to the `.image` property but there is a `String` object and this cause the error.
To read image from your project bundle you need to do it the the following way:

```
colorsPanel.image = UIImage(named: "Red_colors_panel.png") // and do not forget the extension
```